# Deleted C:/Users when deleting symbolic links, can't login now. [Win7]

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link, user-profiles

Running Windows 7 64-bit.

I had symbolic links for `C:/Program Files`, `C:/Program Files (x86)`, and `C:/Users` to `D:/Program Files`, `D:/Program Files (x86)`, and `D:/Users`, respectively.

Tried to solely delete the symbolic links from `C:/`. Turns out Win7 now believes I deleted the real `C:/Users` folder. Now I cannot login, since it fails to load user profiles (only an admin and guest account present). It was my understanding that deleting the symbolic links doesn't delete the content that it redirects to.

**Is there a way to restore `C:/Users` despite all user profiles being unloadable?** Before restarting, I had gone into the Recycle Bin and tried to restore `C:/Users`. Seemed to work at first. Apparently, this is not the case.

P.S. This is an old setup of which I am trying to repair without deleting the files on there. Please don't ask me why there are symbolic links for these folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try booting the install DVD, selecting "Repair my Computer" (instead of "Install Windows") and recreating the symbolic links via Command Prompt, using the `mklink` command: `mklink /D C:\Users D:\Users`

Comment: Turns out that ultimately wasn't the problem. But you did lead me to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @baph0mt: Would you click the "Answer your own question" button and tell what the problem and answer were, and then mark it as the answer?

Comment: It's not an answer, really. Suffice it to say that symbolic links were not the problem.